# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE в eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Во время запуска эмулятора из эклипса все время выпадает ошибка

```
INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
```

В приложении использую очень простую активити, практически как в примерах. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно попробовать запустить через дебаг. Для этого идём в Debug configurations, там проставляем дефолтный эмулятор, который надо запускать, идём сюда: "additional emulator command line options" и прописываем

```
-partition-size 1024
```

Если на данный момент запущен какой-то эмулятор типа AVD, то убить. После запускаем дебаг режим. Ошибка не должна появляться. Подробнее [здесь](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/41852900bd603070/583943d91dc9f754?lnk=gst&q=insufficient+memory#583943d91dc9f754)